# Is it possible for an app to update OTA

Tags: ios, ota

I have developing an app and I have users testing the app for me and there are times that I need to fix a bug and re-upload my app to my site and for my beta testers to download to the newest version. My question is if there is a way for my app to check if there is a new version on the site for it to download and install?

Please remember that I am not going through the app store as of yet, but just having a couple of friends test my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/) to distribute your app's beta among your friends. In order to do that you will just need to archive your app in Xcode and to upload it to Testflight. Your testers will get notifications on app's builds updates via email and will be able download new  builds OTA.

Comment: Just tried this over the weekend. SO far everything seems to be running fine. Thank you.

Comment: You welcome, this tool is one of the most useful non-Apple tools for iOS-development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

no, its not possible yet.

your app can check if an update is availble and then redirect users into the app store page, but you cant update OTA like the core iOS can